How should complex/nested Gradle Extensions be designed in Kotlin?
Say I have a gradle plugin called FooPlugin. Then I define it like so:
abstract class FooPlugin: Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        val extension = target.extensions.create("foo", FooPluginExtension::class.java)
            .apply {
                // apply conventions
            }

        // register tasks
    }
}

but my Extension interface has has nested classes like so:
interface FooExtension {
    val complexProperty: Property<Bar>
    val otherComplexProperty: Property<Baz>
}

and I want the resulting gradle code to look like this:
// build.gradle.kts
foo {
    bar {
        myInt = 1
    }
    baz {
        myBool = true
    }
}

Should I then implement a builder for Bar and Baz myself and define them as classes?, or should I define them as interfaces like so:
interface Bar {
    val myInt: Property<Int>
}

and figure out a way for Gradle to see them as "nested extensions"?.. if that's even a thing.
What's the best practice here?

When you create an extension in Gradle, that extension itself becomes extendable, just like the Project object is by default.
In code terms, this means the extension object will extend the ExtensionAware interface.
Then you can write, for example:
// In plugin

abstract class FooExtension
abstract class BarExtension {
    var myInt: Int = 0
}
abstract class BazExtension {
    var myBool: Boolean = false
}

val foo = extensions.create("foo", FooExtension::class.java)
with(foo as ExtensionAware) {
    val bar = extensions.create("bar", BarExtension::class.java)
    val baz = extensions.create("baz", BazExtension::class.java)
}

And then configure as your example:
// build.gradle.kts

foo {
    bar {
        myInt = 1
    }
    baz {
        myBool = true
    }
}

